How to call embedfile from a subdocument using the relative path?
I want to create documents containing multiple exercises, which I include using the import command from the import package. Depending on which exercise is included, additional files should be embedded into the PDF (using embedfile). Commands like includegraphics are able to work on the local path, embedfile does not.
My question is:
How do I embed a ressource in the exercise file without knowing the path to the main document?
MWE:
Folder Structure:
main.tex
exercises
-- myexercise.tex
-- myimage.png

main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{embedfile}

\begin{document}
    \import{exercises/}{myexercise.tex}
\end{document}

myexercise.tex
The following file should be embedded:

\embedfile{myimage.png} %This does not work
\embedfile{exercises/myimage.png} %This works but needs to know the path

Additional thoughts
As far as I understood, the import package stores the path in \import@path. Maybe this could be exploited to gain knowledge about the current path. Unfortunately, I don't know how.

Try with this in the preamble:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{embedfile}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\filegetfullnameF{}
\let\filegetfullnameF\file_get_full_name:nNF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\EmFi@embedfile
  {\def\EmFi@file{#2}}
  {\filegetfullnameF{#2}\EmFi@file{\def\EmFi@file{UNKNOWNFILE}}}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother


This works great! Thanks you! Could you elaborate what is the key insight for this code? I suppose that with \file_get_full_name:nNF you convert the relative into an absolute path and use this for embedfile. Is that correct?
